# Find 3 vectors orthogonal to a vector in 4 dimensional vector space ($\mathbb{R}^4)$

Tags: linear-algebra

Find three linearly independent vectors in $\mathbb{R}^4$ which are orthogonal to the vector $(3,4,1,-2)$.

How do you start with this?

(From "Schaum's outlines, Tensor Calculus", 2011, exercise 2.8, page 15)

Comment: are you familiar with [Gram-Schmidt](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Gram–Schmidt_process)?

Comment: yes, but, I dont' have a control systems book with me...

Comment: You can also solve the system of linear equations $(3, 4, 1, -1) \cdot (a, b, c, d) = 0$ (there is only one equation) using Gaussian elimination. There will be three free variables and as usual, letting each variable be $1$ while the others are $0$ will yield a basis of solutions, i.e. three linearly independent vectors, each orthogonal to $(3, 4, 1, -2)$.

Comment: does linear independence imply orthogonality?

Comment: i mean, does linear independence of a linear basis set for (a,b,c,d) imply its orthogonal to (3,4,1,-1)?  i could easily have used (1,0,0,0), (0,1,0,0), ..., but doesn't make it orthogonal to (3,4,1,-1)....

Comment: Your title is strange... what do you mean by vectors orthogonal to $\Bbb R^n$?

Comment: All solutions to the equation in @TheoBendit’s comment are a fortiori orthogonal to $(3,4,1,-1)$. You could not have “easily used $(1,0,0,0), (0,1,0,0),\dots,$” because none of those vectors satisfy that equation.

Answer (score 2):

Starting from Vector 1:

$$\mathbf{v_1} = (3,4,1,−2)$$

We want $v_1$ orthogonal to $v_2$, thus:

$$\langle v_1, v_2 \rangle = 0$$

or:

$$(3,4,1,−2) \cdot (a,b,c,d) = 0$$

$$3a+ 4b + c -2d = 0$$

there are infinite number of solutions.  so we pick one that's nice.

let: $a=0, b = 1, c=0$

now we plug in and solve for d.

$$3(0) + 4(1) + (0) - 2d = 0$$

$$4 = 2d$$

$$d = 2$$

this yields vector:

$$v_2 = (a, b, c, d)$$

$$\mathbf{v_2 = (0, 1, 0, 2)}$$

---

To find the next orthogonal vector... we take i, j, k of vector found so far:

$$ \mathbf{v_3} = \left|\begin{array}{c c c c} 
\mathbf{\hat{i}} & \mathbf{\hat{j}} & \mathbf{\hat{k}} \\ 
3 & 4 & 1 \\ 
0 & 1 & 0 \\ 
\end{array}\right| + \mathbf{\hat{l}}x$$

$$\mathbf{v_3} = -\mathbf{\hat{i}} + 3\mathbf{\hat{k}} + \mathbf{\hat{l}}x$$
$$\mathbf{v_3} = (-1, 0, 3, x)$$

scale by constant, ie: multiply each element by -1 and absorb -1 into x:

$$\mathbf{v_3} = (1, 0, -3, x)$$

now we have:

$$(0,1,0,2)\cdot(1, 0, -3, x) = 0$$

solving for x, we find that x=0. thus:

$$\mathbf{v_3 = (1, 0, -3, 0)}$$

---

Finally we can find the last orthogonal vector using the cross product:

$$ \mathbf{v_4} = \left|\begin{array}{c c c c} 
\mathbf{\hat{i}} & \mathbf{\hat{j}} & \mathbf{\hat{k}} & \mathbf{\hat{l}} \\ 
3 & 4 & 1 & -2 \\ 
0 & 1 & 0 & 2 \\ 
1 & 0 & -3 & 0 
\end{array}\right|$$

$$v_4 = (30, -20, 10, 10)$$

rescale each term by a constant:

$$\mathbf{v_4 = (3, -2, 1, 1)}$$

---

ANSWER:

$$\mathbf{v_1} = (3,4,1,−2)$$
$$\mathbf{v_2} = (0, 1, 0, 2)$$
$$\mathbf{v_3} = (1, 0, -3, 0)$$
$$\mathbf{v_4} = (3, -2, 1, 1)$$

Comment: Note that there’s no requirement that the three vectors themselves form an orthogonal set, only that they’re all orthogonal to the given vector.

Answer (score 1):

A comment suggested Gram-Schmidt, but that’s overkill for this problem. Remember how it is you can tell that a pair of vectors is orthogonal: their dot product vanishes. So, write down the dot product of this vector with an arbitrary one and you have a homogeneous linear equation to solve. The $1\times4$ coefficient matrix, you will find, is already in echelon form, so you should be able to read a basis for the solution set directly from it.

Observe that if you choose any pair of elements of the vector, negate one and swap them, then set the rest to zero, you’re guaranteed to get a vector that’s orthogonal to it. If you’re careful about how you pick the pairs, you can quickly produce a linearly-independent set. This is basically the process that you’d go through when reading a null space basis from the coefficient matrix as above.